# MongoDB.Driver.Core find and update using LINQ

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

There are a few solutions online, but I feel like they are kind of "ancient" and there is a better way for it in c#.

I want to find element by id, and change certain value.

```cs
_messages.UpdateOne(message => message.Id == id, filter? message.upvotes++)
```

Code above is obviously bad, but I'm just showing general idea. Is there any good solution to that?

Comment: how about something like [this](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/6d8e9912223eb6228b69fe792782aef4)

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ Despite LINQ it looks more complicated than classic approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to edit the message database-side seems unnecessary, and would require some sort of custom Mongo specific command. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." - Someone smart.

Do it in a couple steps:

```
var message = context.GetCollection<Message>().AsQueryable().First(x => x.Id == id);
message.Upvotes++
var filter = Builders<Message>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
context.GetCollection<Message>().UpdateOne(filter, message);
```

These types of database interactions can fit behind a generic repository interface, avoiding locking yourself into a specific database provider for your application.

```
var message = messageRepo.GetById(id);
message.Upvotes++
messageRepo.Update(message);
```

Comment: 1. What is `filter`? 2. Is `AsQueryable` needed or preferred?

Comment: I added a filter definition in my example above. It's the mongo specific way of identifying which document you're going to update in the database. That mongo specific implementation can easily live behind the generic repo abstraction.

Comment: `AsQueryable` is only needed if you want to interact with Mongo using the `IQueryable` interface. Otherwise, you can just use the Mongo specific query methods. E.g. replace the line in my example with: `var message = context.GetCollection<Message>().Find(filter);` where filter is the same thing as is used with the `UpdateOne()` method.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find element by id, and change certain value.

The following code does that:

```
var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Message>("message");
var filter = Builders<Message>.Filter.Eq("id", someId);
var update = Builders<Message>.Update.Inc("upvotes", 1);
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
Console.WriteLine(result.ModifiedCount);
```

The update is equivalent to MongoDB update operation [db.collection.updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/)